# How to set images in gridview with arraylist of urls?

Tags: android, android-gridview

**SampleGridViewAdapter.java**

```
package com.alifinteractive.viewtext;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class SampleGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    List<String> urls;
    String[] strBook;
    Bitmap bmp;

    public SampleGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> urls) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_image);
        this.context = context;
        this.urls = urls;
        Log.i("DDDDDDDDDD", String.valueOf(urls));
        Object[] mStringArray = urls.toArray();
        strBook = Arrays.copyOf(mStringArray, mStringArray.length, String[].class);
        for (int i = 0; i < strBook.length; i++) {
            Log.i("GGGGGGGGGGG", String.valueOf(strBook[i]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null) {
            view = new ImageView(context);
        }
        loadBookIcons(view, position);
        return view;
    }

    private void loadBookIcons(final View view, final int position) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                try {
                    InputStream in = new URL(strBook[position]).openStream();
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("ERRORRRRRR", e.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                if (bmp != null) {
                    ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(bmp);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

this is my home `Fragment` on which I want to set the `GridView`

```
package com.alifinteractive.viewtext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Home_new extends Fragment {
    //Login login;
    String json;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    String imageUrl;
    //String name;
    ImageView img;
    ArrayList<String> Urls = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home1, container, false);
        //GridView grid=(GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        //grid.setAdapter(new SampleGridViewAdapter(getActivity(),Urls));
        // username=Login.getUserObject(getActivity(), "username");
        // password=Login.getUserObject(getActivity(), "password");
        String oldjson = Login.getUserObject(getActivity(), "order_json");
        json = oldjson.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
        Log.i("QQQQQQQQ", json);
        try {
            JSONArray results = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("CustomerOrders");

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                JSONObject menuObject = results.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("ooooooooo", String.valueOf(menuObject));
                imageUrl = menuObject.getString("image");
                Log.i("FFFFFFF", imageUrl);
                Urls.add(i, imageUrl);

                Log.i("LLLLLLL", String.valueOf(Urls));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("ZZZZZZZ", String.valueOf(Urls));
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I want to set the `adapter` on `GridView` but getting error , help me thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please limit the code in your question to just the relevant parts?

Comment: @ManeatingKoala sorry actualy me new in android thats why ,,, and whenever i call gridview.setadapter(new Sample......) then there come null pointer exception

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: use picasso library http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: com.alifinteractive.viewtext.Home_new.onCreateView(Home_new.java:35)

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar i use that one too bt still the same result

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar using picasso i set the image on imageView staticaly bt while dynamically its getting same eroor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LinearLayout view = new LinearLayout(context);
view.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
view.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
//Icon of Item
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);    
   String url = getItem(position);
   Log.i("AAAAAA",String.valueOf(url));
    Picasso.with(context) //
   .load(url) //
   .error(R.drawable.error) //
   .fit() //
   .into(imageView);
  view.addView(imageView);  

  return view;

}
```